# mailing form in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contact-form

hi im trying to install a contact form in my ruby project where users can send emails to a specified address. I'm having trouble displaying the contact form on my site, keep getting the error *Expected H:/Sites/whatsonnew/app/controllers/contact_form_controller.rb to define ContactFormController*. Any ideas why?

code in the contact form controller

```
class ContactFormsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new
  end

  def create
    begin
      @contact_form = ContactForm.new(params[:contact_form])
      @contact_form.request = request
      if @contact_form.deliver
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
      else
        render :new
      end
    rescue ScriptError
      flash[:error] = 'Sorry, this message appears to be spam and was not delivered.'
    end
  end
end
```

calling the controller by displaying this link

```
<li><%= link_to "Contact Form", controller: 'contact_form', action: 'new'  %></li>
```

routes.rb
 I've tried

```
match 'contact_form/create' => 'contact#create'
match 'contact_form/new' => 'contact#new'
match 'contact_form' => 'contact#new'
```

Comment: @senayar is right, or your file to `contact_forms_controller.rb`. See how the name of the class and file must match!

Comment: thanks, now I get the error 'Could not find table 'contact_forms''

Comment: class ContactFormController < ApplicationController

Comment: How is ContactForm defined?

Comment: i think its because i have a migration called create_contact_forms with the code...                                                 class CreateContactForms < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :contact_forms do |t|
    t.timestamps
    end
    end
    end

Comment: Do you want to store it in the DB? If you do, you need a model and to run the migration, if you don't you shouldn't have a model and a migration, the `.deliver' makes me think you want a Mailer instead, but that's too many things to solve at once and out of the scope of your question. You might want to go back and do things step by step with the Rails guide open.